# how can synchronize two single phase generators?

Tags: single-phase, power-generation, synchronization

I need to a continues power supply for 3 day without interrupt. I use from 2 single phase generators that a generator work for 10 hour and next another startup. for uninterrupted power supply we need synchronization between to generator. can we connect tow generator?
for big 3 phase generator  (<10kw) synchronization can apply with synchronous board but in single phase phase sequence is not important.

Comment: A very similar question here http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/197395/how-to-synchronize-a-generator-on-the-electrical-grid

Comment: How large are the generators? For small ones (<10 kW), it isn't worth the effort; just get a fast transfer switch. Is there some reason your loads can't tolerate the <100 ms transfer time?

Comment: Also note that typically, Diesel/gasoline generators have a motor->Generator->DC (inkl. buffering caps) circuit->inverter setup, i.e. the motor's speed has nothing to do with the generated power freuqency. In these scenarios, you can often just start the second motor, add it to the DC circuit, and then shut down the first one

Comment: @MarcusMüller: Some smaller generators do use  a DC->Inverter technology, but I think most larger generators (and some cheap small ones) do use the alternator output directly, so engine speed does affect the output frequency.  With the inverter-style generators, the inverter input is usually not readily accesible, so your suggested procedure may not be practical.

Comment: @Dave Tweed: The generators is about 6 kvA and load is computers and log data from cameras and sensors.